# Сравнение соседних элементов массива и смена их местами

Tags: массивы, c

Мне нужно сравнить каждый элемент массива из 20 целых чисел с его правым соседом и поменять их местами, если они не совпадают. Вот мой код:

```
int i;
int a[6];

// ввод массива с консоли не привожу

for (i = 0; i < 6 - 1; i++)
{
    if (a[i] != a[i + 1])
    {
        int temp = a[i];
        a[i] = a[i + 1];
        a[i + 1] = temp;
        printf("%d", a[i]);
    }
}
```

Но он не всегда правильно срабатывает, что может быть причиной?

Comment: @himiko, (зевая) Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Comment: не могу сравнить элементы с их правым соседом
пробовала так 
for (k = 0; k < HB - 1; k++)
{
    if (a[k] != a[k + 1])
       break;   
}

но все равно не выходит

Comment: @himiko, сам код верный, что не работает-то? Если прерывается выполнение, то `break` на то и `break`, чтобы цикл прерывать.

Comment: хм, хорошо. если же верный, то как мне поменять элемент с его правым членом? вот с этим вообще проблема, если честно

Comment: @himiko, присвоить левому значение правого, а правому значение левого, пользуясь переменно-буфером. Если в массиве обычные `int`:

    if (a[k] != a[k + 1]) {
        int temp = a[k];
        a[k] = a[k + 1];
        a[k + 1] = temp;
    }

Comment: Очень просто

    if (a[k] != a[k + 1]) {
      typeof(a[0]) t = a[k];
      a[k] = a[k + 1];
      a[k + 1] = t;
    }

Comment: делала так, все равно что-то не то  http://cs606628.vk.me/v606628602/3da5/t7ynq-F0BYY.jpg

Comment: @himiko, для выкладок кода есть [pastebin.com](http://pastebin.com). В таком виде его даже поформатировать не удастся.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/WGB4neq8

Comment: @avp, ну вы, блин, даете :))

    typeof(a[0]) t

Comment: @MDJHD дык эта, цивилизация. И прогресс.

Answer (score 1):

@himiko, знаете, у меня (с минимальными поправками) все работает. У вас цикл обработки доходил до предпоследнего элемента и потому не печатал последний, больше я практически ничего не трогал (кроме форматирования).

Код на [pastebin.com](http://pastebin.com/Y3K8TSKp). У меня линукс, поэтому какие-то заголовки может и зря улетели.

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>


 int main(void)
 {
    int i;
    int a[6];
    for (i = 0 ; i < 6; i++) {
        printf("massiv[%d] = ", i);
        scanf_s("%d", &a[i]);
    }

    printf("--- Processing ---\n");

    for (i = 0; i < 6 - 1; i++) {
        if (a[i] != a[i + 1]) {
            int temp = a[i];
            a[i] = a[i + 1];
            a[i + 1] = temp;
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        printf("massiv[%d] = %d\n", i, a[i]);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
 }
```

```
massiv[0] = 1
massiv[1] = 1
massiv[2] = 2
massiv[3] = 3
massiv[4] = 4
massiv[5] = 1
--- Processing ---
massiv[0] = 1 // в первом случае 1 == 1, ничего не поменялось
massiv[1] = 2 // а дальше два числа поменялись
massiv[2] = 3 // но так как a[1] из-за этого стал a[2], он снова участвует в сравнении
massiv[3] = 4
massiv[4] = 1 // и добирается таким образом до самого низа
massiv[5] = 1
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Очень помогли:)